# JQuery. Check if ASP.NET MVC Form is valid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use ASP.NET MVC client-side validation with data attributes for view models:

```
public class SomeViewModel 
{
  [DataType(DateType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "..."]
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I also have legacy code that uses jquery and handles form submit event:

```
$form.submit(function (event) {
  ...
});
```

submit handler is called every time nevertheless if form is valid or not.
How can I check if form is valid inside this $form.submit handler?

Comment: is your form getting posted back, as it shouldn't and validation should happen on client side

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, form is not postedback, I doublechecked this with network tab in browser. asp.net mvc client-side validators show errors, but jquery submit event is raised also.